# Symfony 2 - Project configuration on production

Tags: symfony

I finished my website based on Symfony2 and It's running on `app_dev.php`. I want to get it visible for users through `app.php`.

1) How can I configure my project so that users can access it through `app.php`?

2) How can I remove `app.php` from the url `domain.com/app.php/{slug}`?

What else do I need to do when finishing developing my website?

Thanks!

Comment: it's all in the excellent documentation!! `cache:clear -e prod; assets:install -e prod; assetic:dump -e prod` and just make sure that your `web/.htaccess` gets parsed by your webserver.

Comment: ok. what does assetic:dump -e prod does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How can I configure my project so that users can access it through app.php?

The `app_dev.php` is used when you are developing your website - Dev environment. So, you can see the developer toolbar. If you finished developing your website, you will need to change to `prod` environment by using the following command:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install web_directory
php app/console assetic:dump web_directory
```

> 2) How can I remove app.php from the url domain.com/app.php/{slug}?

To remove the `app.php` from your url, you can set the web root of your project to the web folder. It's best to do this with apache using virtual hosts, but there are ways to do it with the htaccess.

Here is the example of my `Virtual Hosts`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "path_to_symfonyTest/web"  
    ServerName "symfonyTest"  
    <Directory "path_to_symfonyTest/web">
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/app_dev\.php/(.*) /$1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or If you need to achieve this by using `htaccess`, see this [site](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/)

You can see more information [How to deploy a Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html)

Comment: Just one question, php app/console assets:install web_directory - why should i create new asset, and if i must, where should it be (web_directory)?

Comment: And another question. php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug - i understand this is clearing cache, but what means --env=prod and -no-debug, please tell me. Thanks a lo!

Comment: Please read the documentation! Or execute the commands with the help switch for explanations: `php app/console cache:clear -h`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your vhost definition, provided you use apache:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
```

EDIT: based on comment

then you can set it this way :

```
server {
    index app.php;
}
```

Check this resource too: http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony